# Select and change the image source of nth elment using jquery or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**My HTML:**

```
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
</ol>
```

Here I want to change the image `scr` of:

```
first  li  to  images/car.jpeg
second li  to  images/bus.jpeg
first  li  to  images/boat.jpeg
```

> I want to complete this using nth selector or `eq` function, not with
>   each function. And I can able to select like image inside first `li` of
>   class `flex-control-thumbs`, image inside second `li` of class
>   `flex-control-thumbs` etc.

Please help me to complete this using jQuery, CSS nth selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```js
$('.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs img').eq(0).attr('src','images/car.jpeg');
$('.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs img').eq(1).attr('src','images/bus.jpeg');
$('.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs img').eq(2).attr('src','images/boat.jpeg');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this is not correct way $('img').eq(0) ?? But my page contain many images and this is not the first image .

Comment: @abilasher i limited by the class,is that ok ?updated

Answer (score 2):

To change all the image's `src`:

```js
var images = ['car.jpeg','bus.jpeg','boat.jpeg'];
$('img').each(function(i){
  $(this).attr('src','images/'+images[i])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" class="flex-active" draggable="false" alt="one">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class=""  alt="two">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class=""  alt="three">
    </li>
</ol>
```

To change `src` of a specific image with `eq()`:

```js
var list = $('.flex-control-nav.flex-control-thumbs > li > img');
list.eq(1).attr('src','images/bus.jpeg');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" class="flex-active" draggable="false" alt="one">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class=""  alt="two">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class=""  alt="three">
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: could you please amend this with nth selection like .eq(0), eq(1)  etc. I do't need each function

Answer (score 2):

First select li contained in your flex-control-nav. Then use eq(index) to change image source.This will give you index of first li image

```
a =$('.flex-control-nav li');
a.eq(0).attr('src','images/car.jpeg');
a.eq(1).attr('src','images/bus.jpeg')
```

Comment: I have been through your answers and I like the way you are answering. Please do not take me wrong and I know this is out of concern but I would like to contact you, if you are comfortable.

Comment: Hi@AnkitAgarwal Thanks for your appreciation.we can connect on hangout.My gmail is kataria158@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('li img');
var img = ['images/car.jpeg','images/bus.jpeg','images/boat.jpeg'];
var indx = 0;
images.forEach(function(el){
  el.src = img[indx++];
})
```

```html
<ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" class="flex-active" draggable="false">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
    <li>
       <img src="images/test.gif" draggable="false" class="">
    </li>
</ol>
```